# Вывести результат запроса в виде таблицы

Tags: java, url, request

Мне нужно, чтобы текст выводился не в одну строчку, а таблицей, но я не знаю, как это сделать

Вот код:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
}
```

Может быть можно через `printf`, но я не знаю, как это сделать. Нужно, чтобы вывод был в виде таблицы.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример строки которые вы получаете, чтоб понимать в каком формате к вам приходят данные

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить перенос строки:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
    response.append('\n');
}
```

Тогда результат будет примерно таким:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "7589.89574538", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "21418325570.7", 
        "market_cap_usd": "137716760826", 
        "available_supply": "18144750.0", 
        "total_supply": "18144750.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.01", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.33", 
        "percent_change_7d": "3.28", 
        "last_updated": "1578319298"
    }
    ...
]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)